# Retrieving custom ID-Field value resets ID to 0

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I have a disabled textfield in a PowerApp, which needs to show the ID of the item the user is going to create through my PowerApp.

I have two lists on SharePoint.

The first list is called "ID Config". The list consists of a single element. This element contains an ID in a field called "Deviation_ID".

The second list contains Deviations. Deviations is created through the Power App, and the next-in-line Deviation_ID is assigned to the Deviation the user is creating.

Each time a user opens the Deviation screen in my PowerApp, the ID in ID Config is counted up, once, using this code on the "OnVisible" property:

```
If(Connection.Connected,
  UpdateContext({DeviationID:Text(Value(First('ID Config').Deviation_ID+1),"00000")});
  Patch(
    'ID Config',
    First('ID Config'),
    {Deviation_ID:DeviationID}
  ), Select(Button2)
);
```

However, sometimes the ID fetched is being reset to "00001", instead of counting up once. Meaning the ID fetched from the list is just 0.

Am I missing something, that causes a fail when fetching the current ID from the ID Config list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This here:  `If(Connection.Connected, UpdateContext({DeviationID:Text(Value(First('ID Config').Deviation_ID+1),"00000")`

Sometimes connections drop out for a split second or data doesn't get loaded.  Set a timer to wait until the Deviation_ID has time to load.  Or even better add in a label with the value of .Deviation_ID.  And set your function to use the label's text instead of pulling from the loaded data.

I had a lot of problems with data not getting submitted because I had the edit forms set to Gallery.Selected.  When I switched to using variables to hold the data all those problems went away.

If this is gathered from a gallery in an edit form, setup a variable which holds the gallery items data and use that to display your information.  It works better.  E.G. `Set(_MyVariable, ThisItem) or to Gallery1.Selected`

Comment: I ended up implementing this, and the issue hasn't happened since. Thanks for the solution of using the Connection.Connected variable!